# Intel Fortran Compiler option for automatic dependency generation

Tags: dependencies, fortran, intel, automatic-generalization

Is there an option for automatic dependency generation for INTEL Fortran Compiler, like the "-MM" option of c/c++ compiler, we can use in makefile?

Answer (score 3):

`-gen-dep` does this, but I have problems to make it work when preprocessor is used.

But it is easier to use `Scons` or `waf` than `make` anyway. At least Scons does this totally automatically independently of the compiler.

Otherwise see http://lagrange.mechse.illinois.edu/mwest/f90_mod_deps/

or http://personal.inet.fi/private/erikedelmann/makedepf90/